# Strange chars displaying on page being created through user copy/paste aspx .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, encoding

I have an app where the user is creating a 'tender item' that our company publishes to the public in which anyone can view and then bid upon.

When our internal users create this item, they often copy and paste 'work requirements' into a field that are later used in a dynamically generated .html page.

I am having encoding issues with some of the chars, and don't know how to get them to render correctly.

Specifically:

A short dash is fine ('-'), however there is a longer dash ('–') that displays like this: â€“

Also, I am having trouble with certain single and double quotes, which are giving me this: â€™, â€“, â€œ, and â€.

What do I need to do to fix this?
The app simply reads in this info from a session var, and then I create the html page from there. I have tried to put

```
 `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />`
```

in the head, but this does not help. I have also tried (stab in the dark) to feed the string into a byte array and encoding the array to UTF-8 (thinking that maybe it was from the source?), but this also didn't help.  Once the page is rendered, I check the encoding and it is presented in Western European (ISO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to find a way print the raw HTML Character codes when a user inputs a certain character. For an EM dash, use `&#8212;` , etc.

Comment: Sorry to sound dumb (I'm pretty damn new), but do you mean to just do a simple replace on the string?

Comment: Yeah, that should probably work. I'm not extremely familiar with asp.net, but this is just an issue with HTML character codes. To go further into detail, whats happening is that a user is submitting data, and in that data are characters that can't be used in raw HTML (Such as `&`). When the page is dynamically generated, it is attempting to use those characters, and as a result, is shooting out those strange characters. If you can find a way to replace strings, it'll most likely work. Example: write a line to replace any instances of `&` with `&amp;`

Comment: I tried... Didn't work.. When I do a watch on the string, it is formatted correctly, ie it looks as it should until it is displayed in the browser... There are no ampersands, just the correctly formatted chars (at that point).

Comment: Not really understanding what you mean here...let me reiterate. User submits 'tender item' that contains characters such as a long dash `&#8212;`. Your app is taking the data that the user submits, and creating a dynamically generated HTML page with that data. This is where you need to do some form of conversion: before the page is dynamically generated with your app, you're going to need to find a way to convert any submitted characters into their appropriate character code. When a long dash is submitted by a user, the app needs to generate this onto the HTML page instead: `&#8212;`

Comment: I could be wrong though; I'm assuming that's how your app is working. I'll upvote your post and see if we can get some other users input on this.

Comment: Sorry, I made a comment earlier, but apparently didn't save it (boob).... Instead of doing the replace on ampersands, I just did the replace on the offending char (long dash, crazy apostrophe, whatever), and replaced it with a 'normal' dash, or a 'normal' apostrophe.... My users are all internal, and are all on ie8, so as long as it renders fine there, I'm all good. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Awesome! Yeah the ampersands were just an example, as they are pretty common for HTML codes. If you run into any other characters giving you issues, the replace should just do the trick.